# Which OlSaveAsType can I add to the MailItem SaveAs method?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am getting the currently selected mailItem from the explorer and saving it to the local file system.  The file is then being uploaded to a server.  My problem is sometimes the server (which I have no control over) returns that the file format is invalid.

I save the mailItem with the following code:

```
oMailItem.SaveAs("C:\path\savedEmail.msg")
```

This creates a file which is 174kb in size. If I add the OlSaveAsType of olMSG then I get the same file size.

If I save the exact same email with the Outlook UI then the chosen/suggested Message format is Unicode.  This produces a file of about 251kb ie. much bigger.  If I save it with the above code and olMSGUnicode then I also get the same file size.

I am therefore assuming that leaving out the OlSaveAsType option saves the mailItem as an olMSG.

I am currently also assuming that this may be causing some issues with the upload to the server.

What property of a mailItem tells me which OlSaveAsType to use? Can I safely use olMSGUnicode for all saves?

Comment: Are you saying that the server does not like the .MSG format ever or just some of the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can safely use olMSGUnicode format on all modern versions of Outlook.

But the real problem is why the server (?!) returns an error that the format is invalid?  Was it corrupted? Can you successfully open the same file you sent to the server? You need to figure out why that error is returned.

Comment: Yep it’s Office 2016 so I will implement it. And I totally agree about the server problem. I’m pulling my hair out and going into everything I can think. It’s only MailItems that sometimes cause a problem. All other files including other Office files are no problem. I thought it was how I saved them because it seemed Outlook UI saved .msg worked better.